# Relationship between (PE <> winnt.h ) and (ELF <> elf32.h)

Tags: compilation, executable, elf, portable-executable

**What I know:**
winnt.h contains the structure/definition of PE file and its components (Windows), and ELF32.h contains structure of ELF file and definition of each components(Linux).

**What i think (understanding/observation):**
I understand that the winnt.h not only contains the PE structure/definition but also contains various macros and types (for Windows NT), and it is a child header file of windows.h (so, based on my understanding, winnt.h has another important application to provide win API etc). However, based on my observation, elf32.h only contains definition/structure of ELF file (and nothing more than that.

**My Question**: what is the application/functionality of winnt.h when it comes to compiling/interpereting/executing a PE file? 
I understand that winnt.h has another application (providing Win API/Macros/etc) and is a prefect guide to understand/dismantle a PE file, but how this file is specificly used by the OS?

- Does the compiler use it to build the PE file from source?
- Does the OS use it to interperet the PE file?

*And the same question for ELF32(or 64).h and ELF file.

Any answer is much appreciated.

Comment: in windows wdk exist *ntimage.h* where only contains definition/structure pe/coff (lib,obj) files. the rest question i even don't understand

Comment: I think ntimage is irrelavant here, but which part of the question is not clear?